# str.equals("String") vs "String".equals(str)

Tags: java, string, performance

Is there a performance impact, assuming `str` is a `java.lang.String`, of using `"String".equals(str)` vs `str.equals("String")`? My gut says, "No, the JVM / compiler will optimize the literal string in either case", but I see the first style crop up enough in various codebases and it just looks so unnatural (at least to me), so I figured there must be a reason besides style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only reason for using `"String".equals(str)` (which I find ugly) is laziness, as it saves you the need to check that `str != null` prior to calling `str.equals("String")`.

Performance-wise there shouldn't be any difference. You are comparing two `String` instances either way.

Answer (score 0):

```
"String".equals(str)
```

Does not yield the same result as

```
str.equals("String")
```

if `str == null`.

In the first case, it returns `false`, in the second, it throws a `NullPointerException`.

```
"String".equals(str)
```

Is in fact equivalent to

```
str != null && str.equals("String")
```